# How to get Value of img tag?

Tags: javascript

How can i get value of img tag??? in img tag we have one property named "Value" so i want to know that how can i access this value property in javascript???

I use this code:

```
function addcart()
    {
        $cartvalue=confirm("Would You like to add This Product to Your Cart?"); 
        if($cartvalue)
        {
            var product=document.getElementById('prod1').value;
            alert(product);

        }
    }
```

here prod1 is value of img tag
but it display as undefine in alert

Comment: Can you show us the HTML markup?

Comment: `prod1` is the `value` of the img tag or its `id`? Post your HTML please

Comment: `<img>`s don't have values.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
var product=document.getElementById('prod1').getAttribute('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Um.. I could be way off here, but arn't you looking for the `src` attribute? I don't think that `value` is a valid attribute for the `<img>` tag...

```
var product=document.getElementById('prod1').src;
```

As I see it, the "value" of an image would be the path to the image itself.. That is located in the `src` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK the img-tag normally has no attribute value: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

But the solution of Michael should work.

Alternatively you can try it with jQuery:

```
var product=$('#prod1').attr('value');
```

Comment: @FAngel why? don't understand. your selector isn't correct ;)

Comment: @fan - not at all. Take a look at the code you posted again - you forgot to add the `#` to the selector. Also those two versions of obtaining the value are exactly the same. jQuery simply offers a shorter version with `.val()`. It's better for readability to use the shorter version.

Comment: @alg - there was no mention of jQuery in the OP's question. You are making quite an assumption that using jQuery is an option here... Also please [don't link to w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) :/

Comment: @Lix FAngel was right. .attr('value') is not the same as .val() in this case. Try it http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/9fsXN/ SHAME ON ME

Comment: First - because jquery is a very helpful library, but knowing JS itself you actually know how to work with jquery or any other library, what you could expect from it and so on. And I think you do a harm to everyone who tries to learn pure JS by telling him to start using jQuery. Second - `.val()` is a short hand for pure JS `element.value` which is not available for `IMG`, just as you stated, and you should use `.attr` which is getAttribute in pure JS (not so simple, but that is correct without diving deep)

Comment: Ignoring for a second that we are dealing with invalid HMTL here... `attr('value')` and `.val()` **are** identical when dealing with valid markup. If you don't take care and write invalid HTML then jQuery can't be expected to "just deal with it".