# How to get the name of an image file in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, onload

I'm trying to get the name of the uploaded image file in my HTML. I tried to apply the solutions at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804745/get-the-filename-of-a-fileupload-in-a-document-through-javascript` and `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359913/how-to-get-value-of-img-tag`. They helped me a bit but not fully.
So, my img tag looks just like this:

```
 <img id="imgPreview"  src="Anzeige%20erstellen-Dateien/default_offers_photo-edd8e5ff2d549a9fa1a898b23119931ebd0e745.png" width="500px" height="360px" style="padding-left:15px;" onload="imgListener()"/>
```

and the above function looks like this:

```
function imgListener(imgFile){
    console.log(document.getElementById('imgPreview').src)
}
```

When I run this code it shows me a crazy long text with thousands of letters and digits. That's for sure not what I asked for. 
The console output looks something like this, but only a lot longer:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

I'm using `src` and not `value`. I'm guessing that's what's causing this. but i dont know how else I could access this information,I now know that `value` is not used for img tag. How can I do it, so that I get just the name of the file?

Comment: use `var img = document.getElementById('imgPreview');
console.log(img.src)` to get image src.

Comment: That IS the image source; it's a data URL that encodes the entire image into a string that can be used in place of any URL. Whatever script is setting the image's source is using a data URL for it. (Try it: copy the entire data URL you're getting into your browser's address bar and press enter. You'll see the image.)

Comment: isn't what you suggest just the same as what I'm doing above? Anyways, I tried it. Same result.

Comment: As @IceMetalPunk stated, there is some library / framework / CMS that is converting your images in base64, in order to save space on the disk. There's no a trivial answer to your question

Comment: Are you creating these image tags? You could put the src in the alt attribute, then get document.getElementById('imgPreview').alt.

Comment: @CristianTraìna, really? I just wanna know the name of the image file the user has uploaded. I thought there must be some easy way of doing that

Comment: @armel — This is why you should provide a **tested** [mcve]. I'm speculating you are using the FileReader API to read the image data, generate a data: URL and populate an `<img>` element. There is no name there. There **is** a name in the original File object which you got the data from in the first place.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/src) states that "The `HTMLImageElement` property `src`, which reflects the HTML `src` attribute, specifies the image to display in the `<img>` element". So the fact that you're getting a base64 URI is just weird... perhaps you can create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), so all of us can investigate further?

Comment: @Fahmi i agree. something weird with the image i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works, just tested on a local file and give the correct name. just have to  familiarize yourself with the object properties on the img object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <img id="imgPreview"  src="Anzeige%20erstellen-Dateien/default_offers_photo-edd8e5ff2d549a9fa1a898b23119931ebd0e745.png" width="500px" height="360px" style="padding-left:15px;" onload="imgListener()"/>
    <script>
        function imgListener(imgFile){
            console.log(document.getElementById('imgPreview').attributes[1].textContent);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

let me know if that works

alternative

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <img id="imgPreview"  src="Anzeige%20erstellen-Dateien/default_offers_photo-edd8e5ff2d549a9fa1a898b23119931ebd0e745.png" width="500px" height="360px" style="padding-left:15px;" onload="imgListener()"/>
    <script>
        function imgListener(imgFile){
            let name = document.getElementById('imgPreview').attributes[1].textContent;
            let nameSplit = name.split("/");
            let lastSplit = nameSplit[nameSplit.length - 1];
            console.log(lastSplit);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey that gives the same result as in my code, returns the image source instead of the name of the image file

Comment: i tested it w a jpg instead of a png, hmmm, maybe there is a different object parameter list based on the format. let me try with a local png...

Comment: works fine with a PNG too. using firefox dev editon. Might be something with your image. try testing with another png image. here is the exact on i used.
`https://clipground.com/images/png-tree-clipart-3.png`

Comment: i read the URL just fine too if past the URL as source and dont use a local image. console.log's just fine

Comment: hmm. I've tried both with .png and jpg. doesn't make difference unfortunately

Comment: try using `https://clipground.com/images/png-tree-clipart-3.png` as your image src property and see if you get the right filename. if so it might be an issue with your image

Comment: also you might be getting the right info in a base 64 format, you ever try converting the text from base 64?
`https://www.base64decode.org/`

Comment: ok, your above code helps to show at least my src property right. But whenever I load  another file it shows the image source instead of the files name. I ve tried it with several different jpg and png files...

Comment: try my second option, which splits the URL to just give you the filename in the case its a path

Comment: the second option returns some characters from that image source. but that doesnt look like the file's name. again it only works for the image source. BTW, thanks a lot for helping. l really appreciate it

Comment: both work for me. its going to be something simple. keep working with it. maybe move the file to the same folder. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
function imgListener(imgFile){
  const el = document.getElementById('imgPreview');
  const tmp = document.createElement("div");
  tmp.appendChild(el);
  console.log(tmp.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src").split("/").reverse()[0])
}
```

```html
<img id="imgPreview"  src="Anzeige%20erstellen-Dateien/default_offers_photo-edd8e5ff2d549a9fa1a898b23119931ebd0e745.png" style="padding-left:15px;" onload="imgListener()"/>
```

Create a temporary item and append the image to get the attribute, I don't know if this works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElemntById('whatever the ID is').files[0].name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).